# NumPy-Related Attribute Error in Using Seaborn's Pairplot

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, seaborn

When I run,

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins)
```

I get the error, `AttributeError: 'module 'numpy' has no attribute 'histogram_bin_edges'`. I have installed the most recent version of numpy, pandas and seaborn, and I am not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: This is not reproducible. If you are using Anaconda, I'd try `conda update --all` at the anaconda prompt. If you're using a separate environment than (base), then activate that environment. Otherwise use pip to update numpy, seaborn, pandas, matplotlib (don't use pip if you're using Anaconda). See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW15i.png). I'm voting to close this as not reproducible.

Comment: My response is appropriate, given a working environment, the issue is not reproducible. Which is why there is a flag with that option.